# check box array selector for jQuery validation

Tags: jquery, html, validation

My HTMl:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="subjects[0]" class="checkbox_array" value="1"  />
<input type="checkbox" name="subjects[1]" class="checkbox_array"  value="1"  />
<input type="checkbox" name="subjects[2]" class="checkbox_array" value="1"  />
<input type="checkbox" name="subjects[3]" class="checkbox_array" value="1"  />
<input type="button" id="ss" />
```

jquery:

```
$("#ss").click(function(){
    if($('input[name=subjects\\[\\]]:checked').length<=0)
    {
        alert("No radio checked")
    }
});
```

its not working for me... using class `if($('.checkbox_array:checked').length<=0)`  it work that easy but how can i do with input name selector

Comment: I think you can/should remove the number from inside the array brackets -- `name="subjects[]"` -- if you're using PHP server-side, it will build an array for you automatically.

Comment: Why do you not want to use the `class` selector? It's more semantic, and probably quicker.

Comment: have some many array like this, for code simply used name because if we use class we need to give for all @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: You could surround them in a container, then the class selector would work for all instances, rather than having to change the 'name starts with' selector for every group.

Comment: this is a cms project so if any others edits without coding knowledge they will get confuse so i used numbers, so they can know the groups and also they won't miss the name @Blazemonger

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this using the [`Attribute Starts With Selector`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/):

```
$("#ss").click(function () {
    if ($('input[name^=subjects]:checked').length <= 0) {
        alert("No radio checked")
    }
});
```

Demo: [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/qVdpE/)

Answer (score 6):

```
($('input[name*="subjects"]:checked').length<=0)
```

Will work...

Doc: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/